# Adjust position of a SideBar so that it is positioned in "front" of a NavBar fixed-top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My navbar is getting on top of my sidebar. What I needed was that the side bar "was over" the navbar, so that when the side bar colpasse, the nav bar would be visible.

As the sidebar will collapse, the navbar will need to appear when this happens. To the way it is, it looks like the sidebar gets cut, and ends up losing a space in the sidebar

Side bar/ nav bar image:

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light fixed-top  flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
        <a class="navbar-brand   " href="#"> </a>
        <img src="~/Content/img/Principal_h_cor_RGB.png" alt="Logo" style="width:150px;">
        <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
            <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <div class="sidebar-brand text-center">
                    <a href="#"></a>
                    <div id="close-sidebar">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-header text-center">
                    <h6 style="text-align:center"> 
                        <img src="~/Content/img/boat_block2.png " alt="Logo" style="width:70px;" />
                    </h6>                                       
                    <div class="user-info">
                        <span class="user-name">
                            <strong>@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")</strong> 

                        </span>
                        <!-- <span class="user-role">Administrator</span> -->
                        <span class="user-status">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            <span>Online</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </nav>

 <script>
.sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-top: 45px;
}

    .sidebar-wrapper ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .sidebar-wrapper a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Z-Index of the fixed-top to 10

```
.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```